# Should I develop desktop games using AIR?

Tags: air, desktop-application

I develop flash based games and currently we supply our games as projector files to our clients. Should I make the jump to AIR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know projector enough, but it should be worth your while if it is like other flash files, ie no access to the underlying system.

With Adobe AIR you get
- Access to the local file system - you can read and write files (there are some restrictions)
- Access to an sqlite database on the clientside, which could be handy for storing 'stuff' in

Furthermore, in the next version of Adobe AIR you will be able to interact more and more with the system and other programs your flash/air is running on.

Check out this [link](http://probertson.com/articles/2009/06/24/new-features-adobe-air-athena/) for more info on what's coming in Adobe AIR 2.0 - halfway down the page there's an entry from september that gives you a link to Mike Chambers [presentation](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/09/22/fotb-slides-advanced-desktop-development-with-adobe-air/) in "Flash On The Beach".

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

(sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: What compelling arguments are there for using AIR?